# Removing Title in Android doesn't work

Tags: android

My `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="example.com.kamera">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and my fullscreen activity looks like that:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
}

}
```

Do you have any ideas why my app crashes? I just want to remove the title bar, the label, basically everything.

Crash-Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: example.com.kamera, PID: 23069
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.com.kamera/example.com.kamera.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:351)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:320)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:281)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                      at example.com.kamera.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:22)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

My `styles.xml` looks like that:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

What of these layouts should I call? `android:theme="???"`

Comment: write callstack

Comment: add your crash log

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: @mafioso you need to use AppCompat themes when using AppCompatActivity. see below answer

Comment: in AndroidManifest.xml's applicaion tag put `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` and remove android:theme attribute from activity tag

Comment: Ok, now it works but the title bar is still there. Do you know how to remove that?

Comment: @mafioso have you added code in activity, see my ans below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the code in the `styles.xml` file:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Change the parent to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and it works!

Comment: If you do like this, then by default all your activities will be with no TITLE BAR

Answer (score 0):

if the other parts are correct check this direction for initialization

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

to fix crash use this in the AndroidManifest.xml file:
`<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" ...`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've updated the question, now you can see the crash log

Answer (score 0):

Try this , in your onCreate method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using AppCompatActivity make sure you are using AppCompat's theme.

Change theme tag for application and remove it from activity

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Now, in styles.xml file create one style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Also, in Acitvity class move below lines before setContentView()

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Comment: What should I write into `customize your theme here?`

Comment: Yeah but there is still a title bar etc. and I want to remove that

Comment: update your question with the changes that you have made in code till now